# bash- Assigning a value to a string using a command (rev)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to assign the value of a string to the reversed value of another string (via the 'rev' command).  I know the rev command is used like this:

```
$ echo "hello" | rev
olleh
```

But what I am trying to do is something like this:

```
var="hello"
rav=${$var | rev}
```

I know this isn't correct syntax and it doesn't work, but I was wondering if there was a way to assign a variable using a command, and if so how is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

```
var="hello"
rav=$(echo "$var" | rev)
echo $rav
```

Comment: Putting double-quotes around variable references is almost always a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following may also help you on same.

```
var="hello"
rav=$(rev <<< "$var")
```

Output will be as follows:

```
echo $rav
olleh
```